# Posting invoice in different currency

Tags: income, gnucash, foreign-currency

I've got all my transactions organized in CAD.
Now I've got a new customer that'll pay me in USD. I can open USD bank accounts to handle this, that's not a problem but in GNUcash I created a new invoice, selected my USD account under Income Account but when I want to post he invoice, GNUcash only ever lets me to chose the old CAD Accounts Receivable (eventhouh I've created a USD accounts receivable). Why is this and how do I handle this properly?

Answer (score 2):

For others who might be looking for the same: I figured it out, I needed to adjust the curency of the customer (Business -> Customer Overview -> [Customer] -> Billing Information, then I was able to choose the correct accounts receivable account (USD)!